# IP address issue java deploy inside a web browser (deployed with dtjava.js)

Tags: java, web-services, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an application deployed using dtjava.js method. The code below shows how my deployment is done.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></script>
<script>
    function deployIt() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {            id: "my",
                        url: "Hello.jnlp",
                      width: 300,
                     height: 200,
                placeholder: "place"
            },
            {
                    jvm: "1.6.0+",
                 javafx: "2.1+",
                jvmargs: "-Dapp.property=somevalue -Xmx1024m"
            }
        );
    }
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(deployIt);
</script>
</head>
<body>
JavaFX below
<div id="place"></div>
JavaFX above
</body>
```

If my application needs to access a database server with host name as "localhost", where would it point to?  Would it be the web server I deployed the JAR or to the PC that opens the browser? Is it allowed to access external IP address?

Thanks for your help and comments

Answer (score 0):

Despite of being a very old thread, questions still get their answers ;)

This hasn't something to do with JavaFX itself, it mostly is how the local DNS-result is resolved. Normally "localhost" will be resolved to 127.0.0.1, so you have to change that name to the real database-server/host.

For being able to open a connection this depends how your MANIFEST-file looks like, you need special permission for this. When using the javafx-maven-plugin, you should specify the option [`<allPermissions>`](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zenjava/javafx/maven/plugin/WebMojo.java#L93) for this. It's a java-security thing.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that maven-plugin.